# Excel VBA: Search and Replace If/Conditional

Tags: vba, excel

Can we do this with VBA?

If text on column A = "Student" and text on column B = "John", replace B text with "John Paul".

Comment: Where is the Logic? Where did `Paul` come from?

Comment: Yes we can do this. What have you tried so far by yourself? And did you try using the SO search or maybe google?

Comment: Please let us know what logic we should use? If column B is John then will it be always John Paul ?

Comment: I wonder why everyone cares about the meaning of the question. The question is related to VBA basics, unless more information is provided.

Comment: @stribizhev If the question is as simple as your answer implies then there's most likely a duplicate somewhere on the site, which would mean this question needs to be closed as a dupe. As it stands it's already either 'Too Broad' or 'Unclear', depending on your personal interpretations of those close reasons. Those asking for clarification want the OP to improve his question so it's a good fit for SO, instead of wasting their time answering crap. Unclear questions probably shouldn't be answered because a clarification could make your answer entirely invalid and it justifies the crap question.

Comment: This is just an example: If A "student" matching B "John", then we should B "Paul" to "Jonh Paul", or any other name we want, like "Andy".

Comment: @user2992797 You need to provide more than just an example and you should show evidence of attempting the problem yourself as well as detailing what's not working with your own attempted solution. As it stands the only actual question in your post is "Can we do this?" to which the answer is objectively "Yes" but I strongly suspect that won't solve the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score -2):

Answering my question. Works for me:

```
Sub ChangeJohn()

Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer

x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To x

If Range("A" & i).Value = "Student" Then
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "John" Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = "John Paul"
    End If
End If

Next i

End Sub
```